# Django with Jeditable: POST renders the whole page into table cell

Tags: django, jeditable

use case:
user click on comment column to leave a comment. 
comment is sent via post to the server.
server uploads to the database.

however instead of merely updating the page, Django puts my whole page into the into the table cell

before: 
http://i50.tinypic.com/28cdkb7.jpg

after:
http://i45.tinypic.com/346vuag.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://formerlyconversal.wordpress.com/2009/11/01/inline-editing-with-jquery-jeditable-and-django/

you are probably looking for this.